# Twig templates on volatile environment (EC2)

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, twig, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Elastic Beanstalk environment with ec2 instances. Since these are volatile, we can't rely on them to store files.

This is a codeigniter app using Twig template system and users can edit the template files.  Currently these template files are stored in the file system (vps).

When we migrate to elastic beanstalk, we no longer can store the file templates as we do now.

What's the best approach to this? S3? Elasticache (memcached) ?

Comment: How do the users edit the template files? How often do the users edit the template files?

Comment: It's a code editor and it saves static files on the file system. 
Users edit the files as they please, but they are accessed all the time by the  frontend clients. So it's an intense reading task, that's why Twig rely on physical files vs database stored content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description it seems you have two main requirements -

1. Frequent read access
2. Durable persistence

Like you said using filesystem storage is not scalable or reliable for your usecase.

I think you should consider using Elasticache backed by DynamoDB. Since you care about persistence Elasticache alone is not a feasible solution. DynamoDB will provide you durability that Elasitcache does not provide.
DynamoDB reads have low read/write latencies so it may turn out to be pretty fast for your use case.

Dynamo DB can give you fast reads and writes. Here is a presentation on this topic that you might find helpful: http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2013/Talks/dig-seminar-0926-daniela.pdf

Your Dynamo DB schema will depend on how your data is structured, if you want to maintain a history of file edits etc. You can also just store a file in S3 which is cached using Elasticache but that may not give you enough flexibility. If you want to be able to write parts of file with S3 you will have to rewrite the entire file everytime a file is edited. But with Dynamo DB you can get the advantage of structuring your storage such that you can edit chunks of file on demand. Also with S3 you have to remember your reads will be eventually consistency. Dynamo DB supports both Strong and Eventual Consistency.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I'll need to measure and benchmark the 2 options: dynamodb vs physical storage via s3.  Both options backed by elasticache. In your opinion what will perform best?

Comment: A third option could be Elastic Block Store volumes (http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/). I would "guess" that with DynamoDB you can get very good performance with the right schema. Also if you want to add advanced IDE features later on, you get more flexibility with DynamoDB.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiarized with EBS volumes.  Would that be persistent? Does it play well with elastic beanstalk?

Comment: "Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) provides persistent block level storage volumes for use with Amazon EC2 instances in the AWS Cloud.  Each Amazon EBS volume is automatically replicated within its Availability Zone to protect you from component failure, offering high availability and durability." http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/
So yes they are persistent. It is like having a file system on the cloud.

Comment: They work with beanstalk. Read about BlockDeviceMappings option setting here. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html

Comment: Great. A file system on the cloud. I like this option because since it is a file system there is no need to change and adapt the code to work with s3 or dynamodb. Do you see any downside using EBS for this particular problem?

Comment: I don't see any downside. I would recommend start benchmarking with EBS first and if it meets your need then go for it. Try adding elasticache only if the performance is not good enough.

Comment: If you still want to go faster scale to larger number of users consider using DynamoDB. First benchmark. EBS also provides provisioned IOPS and SSD volumes so you should consider using those.